# ifstream ofstream on mac

Tags: c++, macos, ofstream

I'm trying to read in a random file (on mac-xcode) and determine the instances of the letter k in the document. Then print the number as an outout file. My problem is that the outfile isn't being written and the nums_k is coming back as 0. I'm not sure if the ifstream is working incorrectly or the ofstream need a different filename established. Here's my source code.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>  
using namespace std;  

int main() { 

    ifstream infile("Users/bryanmichaelnorris/documents/extra credit    assignment.docx"); 

    string line; 
    int numks = 0;  

    while (getline(infile,line)) {     
         int x = 0;         
         for (std::string::iterator it=line.begin(); it!=line.end(); ++it) {            
             if (line[x] == 'k') {                 
                  numks++;            
             }            
             x++;         
         }     
    }         

    infile.close();     
    ofstream outfile("number of k's.docx");   
    outfile << "There are " << numks << " K's in the file." << endl;
    outfile.close();        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"Users/..."`, I'd start by putting a `/` on the *beginning* of that name. And if you want validation your input file opened correctly, it certainly wouldn't hurt to *test* it rather than assume all is right in the world. You may also want to research where the output file is being written, as the current working directory while running under Xcode is usually nothing close to what people think it is (but you can change it in your schema editor).

Comment: @WhozCraig has almost certainly hit the nail on the head

Comment: Don't use `.docx` extension for a file that is not a MS-Word document... If you really need an extension, maybe `.txt` is a much better one. If the input file is also a MS-Word file, then I would not count letter 'k' this way, because you may have 'k''s used for something else than than the text itself.

Comment: BTW: `k` being zero shows that the input fails, so the output is completely irrelevant. Try to reduce your problem to the bare minimum next time. This is also the reason it's required by site rules.

Comment: this was my first question on here, apologies for the inconvenience of my formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Added validations for the opened files.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char * csInputFileNane="Users/bryanmichaelnorris/documents/extra credit    assignment.docx";
    ifstream infile(csInputFileNane);
        if (!infile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Cannot open file \""<<csInputFileNane<<'"'<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    string line;

    int numks = 0;

    while (getline(infile,line))
    {   int x = 0;
        for (std::string::iterator it=line.begin(); it!=line.end(); ++it)              {
            if (line[x] == 'k')
            {
                numks++;
            }
            x++;
        }
    }
    infile.close();
    const char *csOutFileName="number of k's.docx";
    ofstream outfile(csOutFileName);
    if (!outfile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Cannot open file \""<<csOutFileName<<'"'<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    outfile << "There are " << numks << " K's in the file." << endl;
    outfile.close();
    return 0;

}
```